# VirtualHost Apache2

Tags: virtualhost, apache2.2

I try to configure virtualhost with Apache2 on Ubuntu like that (LAMP Stack on docker) :

- test1.domain.com -> /var/www/html/test1
- test2.domain.com -> /var/www/html/test2
- test3.domain.com -> /var/www/html/test3

The path root is /var/www/html

My virtual host has configurated for ssl too.

When i try to call url with ssl (https), it's work, but if i try without ssl (http), i go to path root (/var/www/html). I don't understand why.

- https://test1.domain.com -> /var/www/html/test1 = OK
- http://test1.domain.com -> /var/www/html = NOK

I also need to redirect http to https.

**Default VHOST File :**

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.32.3:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
    ServerName 192.168.32.3
    ServerAlias 192.*
    ServerAlias *:*
        <Directory ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Allows HTTPS on localhost. You will need to use mkcert on your local machine
# to create the `cert.pem` and `cert-key.pem` files, and then place them in the
# `./config/ssl` directory. You could also create certificates for any local
# testing domain you wish such as `localapp.test`, you will then edit your hosts
# file to map that domain name to 127.0.0.1 and then configure your vhosts below
# accordingly:
#
# <VirtualHost *:443>
#     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#     DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
#     ServerName localhost
#       <Directory ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}>
#               AllowOverride all
#       </Directory>

#     SSLEngine on
#     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
#     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert-key.pem
# </VirtualHost>
```

**VHOST File test :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test
    ServerName test1.domain.com
        <Directory ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Allows HTTPS on localhost. You will need to use mkcert on your local machine
# to create the `cert.pem` and `cert-key.pem` files, and then place them in the
# `./config/ssl` directory. You could also create certificates for any local
# testing domain you wish such as `localapp.test`, you will then edit your hosts
# file to map that domain name to 127.0.0.1 and then configure your vhosts below
# accordingly:
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test
    ServerName test1.domain.com
        <Directory ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test>
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    /// CERTIFICATE CONFIG ///ls
</VirtualHost>
```